# Unable to read CSV file when uploading to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: spring-boot, csv, google-cloud-platform, filenotfoundexception

My Spring Boot Application structure is this
[Spring boot app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgjBf.png)

Within `csvService.java` class, I am trying to read the `test.csv` file. I am able to read it on **localhost** but when I deploy it to Google Cloud Platform, it fails to read the file giving **FileNotFoundException**.

This is the line of code responsible for reading the csv file:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(newFileInputStream("test.csv"), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: Do you see test.csv listed when running `ls`?

Comment: yes when i run ls on local machine i can see the csv file

Comment: Of course you will see it on your local machine - the file did not get propagated into your means of distribution. If you're making a jar file, it's not packaged inside. If you want it there, you'll have to make it a resource. Otherwise access it on the fly, for example from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Put it inside the resources folder and tried this
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(newFileInputStream("src/main/resources/config/test.csv"), "UTF8"));

Comment: The question initially read "Google Cloud Console" - there the assumption being running it in the Cloud Shell container.

Answer (score 1):

The file structure is not the same where you deployed it and the `test.csv` file likely did not get packaged in your binary. Thus you're getting a **FileNotFoundException** - the file simply isn't where it was on your local machine.

Things to specify/clarify for your project:

1. Where and how do you deploy? Is it **GKE**, **GCE** or **AppEngine**? Look up for each of those *how* they behave when you deploy a jar file.
2. Why do you want to deploy a `test.csv` file in production? Surely you want to fetch that csv file on fly and not statically (*unless it has some specific meaning*) - if you **do**, put it in the **resources** folder and treat it as such. You will need to slightly alter your file reading code.

Comment: I added the csv file in the resources folder and tried to read it like this
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(newFileInputStream("src/main/resources/config/test.csv"), "UTF8"));

Comment: Is this the correct way or some other path has to be given

Comment: its Google Kubernetes Engine

Comment: No you mustn't use absolute path. Use [this example](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-read-file-from-resources-folder/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was in the Docker file. The image was getting created and wsa only using the jar. I needed to add the below line in the Docker file.
COPY --from=builder /app/test.csv /test.csv